# Select query with outer join

Tags: java, sql, oracle, outer-join

I have two tables Files and Employees.

Files :

### File_ID|  FileName   |   ModifiedBy

```
   1      a.java        10
   2      b.java        11
```

Employees:

### ID| Name

10      Rahul
11      Priya
12      Rohith

What I am trying to do is, print all the fileNames and the person who modified that file. I have to get the modifiedBy persons'name from the table employee using the employee ID. If the employeeID doesnot exist in Employees table, it must not throw an error.
I am asked to do it using outer join. Kindly help in doing this as I am new to this topic

Comment: Did that person tell you why to do an outer join? Can you add expected result also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT F.filename, E.name 
FROM Files AS F 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees AS E 
  ON F.modifiedBy = E.ID
```

The `Files` table: (with an extra, non existant `modifiedby` id)

[image: Files]

The `Employees` table:

[image: Employees]

Output:

[image: Output]

**EDIT:**

Since you're using the **Oracle** DBMS, you need to drop the `AS` keyword:

```
SELECT F.filename, E.name 
FROM Files F 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees E 
  ON F.modifiedBy = E.ID
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But when I try to do the same I am getting sql error:ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"                                      I am doing in oracle

Comment: Ah it's Oracle, not MySQL. Try removing any **AS** keyword from the command & try again.

Comment: Now its perfect! Thank you so much..It was really helpful

Comment: I am now having another column in the table Files 'ApprovedBy'. So I also need to print the ApprovedBy Name, using the ApprovedBy ID that I get from Files table and its corresponding name from the Employees table. Please help

Comment: @TeenaSam please post a new question with the new tables' schemas, I would be glad to help.

Comment: I am not able ask as a new question as I have already a posted question today...I am not being permitted